# Comparing two obstructions of splitness in $\textrm{Ext}^1$

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra, derived-functors

Suppose
$$\xi: 0\to B\to X\to A\to 0$$ is a short exact sequence of R-modules, where $R$ is a commutative ring.

Applying the Ext functors $\textrm{Ext}^*(A,-)$ to $\xi$, we get an exact sequence
$$
\textrm{Hom}(A,X)\to \textrm{Hom}(A,A) \stackrel{\partial}{\to} \textrm{Ext}^1(A,B),
$$
and $\xi$ is split if and only if $\partial\,(\textrm{id}_A)=0\in \textrm{Ext}^1(A,B).$

On the other hand, applying $\textrm{Ext}^*(-,B)$ to $\xi$, we get an exact sequence
$$
\textrm{Hom}(X,B)\to \textrm{Hom}(B,B) \stackrel{\partial'}{\to} \textrm{Ext}^1(A,B),
$$
and $\xi$ is split if and only if $\partial'\,(\textrm{id}_B)=0\in \textrm{Ext}^1(A,B).$

Is $\partial\,(\textrm{id}_A)$ always equal to $\partial'\,(\textrm{id}_B)$?

Comment: Yes, they differ by a sign, and are equal to the class of $\xi$ in $\mathsf{Ext}$. I think someone had asked this before and I had computed it explicitly, but now I cannot find it...

Comment: Here it is: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2871014/the-images-of-the-identity-maps-under-the-connecting-homomorphisms/2872192#2872192. Does it answer your question?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thank you very much!  In your computation, should the line $$a''\to \textrm{class}(a'',0) = \textrm{class}(0,-fa'') \simeq -fa''\in  A,$$ be $$a''\to \textrm{class}(a'',0) = \textrm{class}(0,fa'') \simeq fa''\in  A,$$ instead?  Because by definition, we have $\textrm{class}(a'',-fa'')=0$, so $\textrm{class}(a'',0) = \textrm{class}(0,fa'')$. Does that mean they are supposed to be equal instead of differ by a sign?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff In your earlier answer, you identified $Ext^1(A,-)(B)$ with $Ext^1(-,B)(A)$ by both identifying them with the set of equivalence classes of extensions. There is another canonical identification of $Ext^1(A,-)(B)$ and $Ext^1(-,B)(A)$ using double complexes, as given by Theorem 2.7.6 of Weibel: An introduction to homological algebra.  Are those two identifications the same?  This question is actually asked by another post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1684166/are-those-two-ways-to-relate-extensions-to-ext-equivalent?rq=1 and there is no answer so far. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you're right. I'll see what I can do. For the moment, shall I close this one as a duplicate of the post I linked to?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Yes, that makes sense.  Is it possible to also link it with the other question on the equivalence of two identifications?  That question is still unanswered and it would be nice to resolve that question too.  Thanks a lot!